# Why my Sitecore 9.1 instance started to complain about missing xdb.processing.pools and xdb.processing.tasks connection strings?

Tags: xdb, processing

My **Sitecore 9.1 XP1 Scaled** dev instance started to spam the following exceptions in its log, related to the **xdb.processing.pools** and **xdb.processing.tasks** connection strings:

```
  23372 12:47:01 ERROR Exception when executing agent processing/taskAgent
  Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
  Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source: mscorlib
     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
     at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConstructorParameters(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.CreateAgent()
     at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.<ExecuteAgentAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
     at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.<RunAsync>d__26.MoveNext()

  Nested Exception

  Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
  Message: A connection string with the name 'xdb.processing.tasks' is not configured.
  Source: Sitecore.Analytics.Sql
     at Sitecore.Analytics.SqlUtility.LookUpConnectionString(String connectionStringName)
     at Sitecore.Analytics.SqlDataProvider..ctor(String connectionStringName, Int32 commandTimeout, IRetryManager retryManager)
     at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.SqlTaskDataProvider..ctor(String connectionStringName, Int32 commandTimeout, Int64 ownershipTimeoutMs, Int32 minimumRangeSize, IRetryManager retryManager)
```

and

```
  18288 12:47:01 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/aggregator
  Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
  Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source: mscorlib
     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
     at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConstructorParameters(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConstructorParameters(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
     at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.CreateAgent()
     at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.<ExecuteAgentAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
     at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.<RunAsync>d__26.MoveNext()

  Nested Exception

  Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
  Message: A connection string with the name 'xdb.processing.pools' is not configured.
  Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Processing.Queue.SqlServer
     at Sitecore.Xdb.Processing.Queue.SqlServer.ConfigurationConnectionStringResolver.Resolve(String name)
     at Sitecore.Xdb.Processing.Queue.SqlServer.SqlServerProcessingPool`2..ctor(TPoolDefinition poolDefinition, SqlServerProcessingPoolSettings settings, IConnectionStringResolver resolver, IRetryManager retryManager)
     at Sitecore.Xdb.Processing.Queue.SqlServer.SqlServerInteractionLiveProcessingPool..ctor(ProcessingPoolDefinition definition, SqlServerProcessingPoolSettings settings, IConnectionStringResolver resolver, IPerformanceCounters performanceCounters, IRetryManager retryManager)
```

As far as I know nothing in the XConnect / xDB configuration changed.

For the past three months I never had such connection strings and never had this  error message.

I do have two SQLServer databases named **XPScaled910_Processing.Pools** and **XPScaled910_Processing.Tasks** but after checking BitBucket I never had associated connection strings.

**QUESTION(s)**

- Are there situations where I don't need them, and why the initial installation did not configure them?
- What causes Sitecore to actively look for them?
- Do I just have to create such connection strings?

Comment: What is server role where you are getting this error?

Comment: Content Management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The databases *processing.pools* and *processing.tasks* are used by the analytics processing agents. If your instance has a *Standalone* or *Processing* role in *web.config*, these agents will be executed.

You will need to set up the connection strings if you plan on using Experience Analytics.

Comment: Thank you, this turned out to be the case. Do you have any idea why before I wasn't getting this error?

Comment: Maybe you had "ContentManagement" as local role at first or some other config was disabling processing.